# Meaning of "A Moment's Worth"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the "a moment's worth" in the following

> Using this equation, we can generate the graph with a moment's worth of calculation and plotting.

Is it equivalent to "more acurate" and "faster" or depends on the subject of the context?

Comment: It means *a short period of*.  You should check out English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: Excuse me for this question.

Comment: I don't mean that as an insult.  Our sister stack exchange site is best suited for people who are learning English.  We regularly refer people to it as a way of helping them to improve their skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the equation is so easy/helpful/accurate that you can quickly make some calculations and generate a graph - it will only take a moment.

The equation might make your calculations more accurate, but the 'moment' is a measurement of time, therefore it is referring to the speed of the whole operation.

Comment: It might not actually imply any ease or helpfulness.  It may just be, *now that we have our equation* a moment's worth of work yields our graph.